# Update IBOutlet of UIScrollView with new content

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have made a paging using UIScollView. Pages are created 2 and when user scroll it's changes.

Created page is loaded with new content.

Same page have other UIScrollView with UItextView of subviews.

But when i scroll to other page, my UItextViews added to page UIScrollView don't upadtes.

It's updates just then when i scroll that UIScrollview.

Tried this:

```
for (UIView *childView in _scroller.subviews)
{
    [childView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

But this not helping

Maybe some one have other suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing it on the main Thread?

Comment: Yes, bu i first remove all subviews of ScrollView and then add new content